# Can I statically find/access an android view outside of an application?

Tags: android, view

I am connecting the phone to adb and was wondering if there was a way to access a view outside of an application.

Thanks.

(Similar to Hierarchy Viewer, but being able to look at the data associated with the View [the content that one might find in an XML])

Comment: How exactly and from where do you want to access it? Whats the purpose?

Comment: I think you have to start the application process first, before you can access any of the views. Kinda an important security feature. Imagine the backdoors that could be made otherwise. But... I don't have any concrete facts to show you.

Comment: Well the main idea would be to be able to do the things that Hierarchy Viewer does, but being able to see more information, like you would find in the XML describing the view.

Answer (score 1):

> I am connecting the phone to adb and was wondering if there was a way to access a view outside of an application.

Romain Guy just released his [ViewServer](https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer) within the past couple of hours, which allows Hierarchy View to examine UIs on a device the way it can examine UIs on an emulator. However, this requires adding code to your application -- as @lobner indicates, this is a serious security issue, which is why the platform does not expose this sort of information by default.